# Compute $\iint \sqrt {\frac {1-x^{2}-y^{2}}{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy $

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Compute $$\iint \sqrt {\frac {1-x^{2}-y^{2}}{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy $$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$

I used polar coordinates then $\sqrt {\dfrac {1-r^{2}}{1+r^{2}}}r\,\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta$, but couldn't continue.

Thanks for helping

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2}}\,r\,dr=\frac12\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}\,du$$

Comment: how can i proof  this inequality@MarkViola

Comment: Well, it is an Equality, not an inequality.  Substitute $u=r^2$.

Comment: tthanks for help @MarkViola

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Then since $x\mapsto\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is an involution, the last integral equals $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{(1+x)^2}\,dx$ or $\frac{\pi-2}{4}$.